# Long name in UIButton shortens

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a `UIButton` which has a title longer than the width of the button itself. While in a `UITextField` I see the first part of the string (which is the one I want to show) and then three dots, on the `UIButton` I see the first part, then towards the center three dots and then the third part. Is there a way to fix this issue without actually cutting the string?

Comment: Change the font size or make the button bigger

Comment: `button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth; button.titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 5;` (`minimumScaleFactor = 0.2` for iOS6)

Comment: Since I don't want the second part of the string to be seen i'll go for adjustfontsizetofitwidth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the button size can't change but the titleLabel size can, you can either change the font in of the button in interface builder or in code or allow the label to adjust its font with:

```
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

If the button size can change, you could adjust that rather then the font size:

```
CGRect frame;
frame.origin = self.button.frame.origin;
frame.size = [self.button.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.button.titleLabel.font];
self.button.frame = frame;
```

Alternatively, if you want the line to break at the end of the string instead of the middle, similar to how a UITextField appears, just set the `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`